# Four kings with special abilities

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, malchut-royalty

I heard from one rabbi about 4 king, each of them has a special ability: one ran fast, one saw far away, one has a good memory. And Hashem punished them accordingly: the first was ill with a gout, the second was blind and so on. But he can't remember where did he read  about it. Does it have any source?

Comment: You mention four kings, but only list three abilities. Plus, where do you even learn about these four kings? Is it some Midrash?

Comment: @ezra I don't remember about 4th. And I don't remember where I did read it, but it looks like a midrash

Comment: The best I can come up with is that King Solomon could talk to animals, King Nimrod had a magical garment that also gave him powers over animals, and Idi Amin could play the accordion.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Idi Amin was not a king.

Comment: He was the Last King of Scotland

Answer (score 2):

This seems to come from a *beraita* quoted in [Sotah 10a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.10a.10?lang=bi) regarding five individuals, four of whom were kings (or would-be kings):

> ת"ר חמשה נבראו מעין דוגמא של מעלה וכולן לקו בהן שמשון בכחו שאול בצוארו אבשלום בשערו צדקיה בעיניו אסא ברגליו
>
> The Sages taught: Five individuals were created with a characteristic that is akin to a representation of the One on High, and they were all stricken by that characteristic. Samson in his strength, Saul in his neck, Absalom in his hair, Zedekiah in his eyes, and Asa in his feet.